# Knockoutjs jquery UI modal dialog does not render

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to incorporate one of Ryan Niemeyer's jsFiddles http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/ into my own jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MgzQx/11/, but to no avail.  What I want to happen is for a jQuery UI modal dialog to show when you click next to either of the Contract Line Item edit buttons.  I am fairly positive that it is due to my lack of JavaScript/JSON knowledge that it is not working, so I am asking for help of why it does not work and more importantly for advice on books, tools or debuggers for JavaScript/JSON/Knockout that will help me learn.  jsFiddle is giving me zero indication as to why it does not work.

Karl

Comment: No, I had responded to another comment, which I believe I inadvertently edited.  The original comment asked where my code was, as I had both jsFiddle URLs pointing to the same location.  I have fixed the second URL (my jsFiddle).  I am still experiencing the problem.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Karl - I don't see where you are trying to show the UI dialog?? Did you link to the correct fiddle?

Comment: Okay, it has been one of those days.  I have updated the fiddle, so please now try http://jsfiddle.net/MgzQx/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too sure what behavior you are after so I had a guess. Here is an example that shows a dialog when the top right hand edit button is pressed.

Hopefully this should put you on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/HK4US/

As for learning Javascript I would recommend anything by Douglas Crockford or John Resig. I think you need to know at least the basics of JS before tackling knockout head on. The tutorials for KO are the best way to get started.

JSfiddle in itself is not meant as a debugger, instead it is suppose to be a tool to allow people to exchange and showcased coding problems/issues. For debugging in browser it really has to be Firebug for Firefox, in fact the only reason i have FF installed is for the Firebug plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out; both the books and your example fiddle.  Thanks for the Firebug tip too, I have used it in the past with jQuery/AJAX debugging.

Comment: @Karl - No problem. If this answers your question please mark it as the answer. Thanks.